# nodejs app receive data from post and render to html

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I'm just starting to use node.js and I can't quite understand few things. So please don't be mean. I tried to search the web without much results.

I want one webpage to go on wait for a post and then render the data received.
so far I was have the following app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing 
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    app.set('view engine', 'pug');

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.render('index', {title: 'GET test',message : 'GET test'});
    });

    var data = "";

    app.post("/",function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.method);
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(req.url);
    data=req.body
    console.log(data);
    res.render('index', {title: 'POST test',message : 'POST test'});

    });



    app.listen(8081, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 8081!');
    });
```

in `views/index.pug` I have

```
    html
     head
      title = title
     body
      h1 = message
```

And whenever I trigger `curl --data "field=value" http://127.0.0.1:8081/`
I can see the post received inside the terminal but I can't understend how to render this data in a page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send dataresponses upon POST execution such as :

```
 res.status(201).send("POST executed successufully");
```

Then, within you Javascript call; you catch POST response and render what you want with something like :

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Where am I supposed to put the ajax code?

Comment: Ajax code is on html/JS part (front end) That consume tour webservice

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're not passing data into the res.render method.

```
console.log(data);
res.render('index', {title: 'POST test',message : 'POST test', postData: data});

html
 head
  title = title
 body
  h1 = message
  span = postData.field
```

^ This is under the assumption "field" is present in the post body, in practice you'd want to do this in a more dynamic fashion and make sure it exists.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that the page doesn't change. I want to have something that render the page with "Post test" whenever it receive a post.